# Xcode - Setting a custom date for UIDatePicker from an NSDate property

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker that stores a chosen date in the property (`_selectedDate`). How do I display the property's date on the DatePicker when the view loads instead of its default date (today)?

I read an answer on here that suggested the code below is how to do it, but my app crashes when I try it.

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSDate *selectedDate;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [datePicker setDate:_selectedDate];
}
```

Comment: Why bother checking if `_selectedDate` is nil, if you're immediately going to overwrite it?

Comment: I think I'm asking the wrong question here. Let me revise it.

Comment: This should already be working if both  `_selectedDate` and `datePicker` have valid values. Are you sure that you have connected the outlet in IB?

Comment: Better delete this one if you think you are asking a wrong question? Other people are still reading questions and you are basically wasting their time.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your picker's date in viewWillAppear: rather than viewDidLoad, and also add a custom setter for your selectedDate property. When it changes, change the date in the date picker.

In both places only set the date picker's date if the selectedDate value is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `self.` in front of both `datePicker` and `selectedDate`.
It also may help if you set `self.selectedDate` to an actual `NSDate` as well

Answer (score 0):

At viewDidLoad, are you sure you have the selectedDate setup correctly? is it a non nil value? what is the crash trace?

Comment: I wrapped it inside an if statement `if (valueExists == 1) {[datePicker setDate:_selectedDate];}` so it no longer crashes when there's no value. The problem now is that my UIDatePicker doesn't change to the date stored in `_selectedDate`. It always shows today's date.

Comment: when you change selectedDate, you need to update the picker with the new date